# Proving $(a+b)^{p} \equiv a^{p} + b^{p} \pmod{p}$ for prime $p$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am having trouble proving that any prime number $p$ and integers $a$ and $b$,

> $(a+b)^{p} \equiv a^{p} + b^{p} \pmod{p}$

Comment: Do you know binomial expansion?

Comment: [Freshman's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream). It is difficult to answer this suitably without knowing your approximate level. High school? Freshman?

Answer (score 7):

The binomial theorem says that $$(a + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^k b^{n-k}.$$
When $n$ is prime, 
then for every $0 < k < n$ we have 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = n\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
because nothing in the denominator divides $n$. 
So all of the middle terms in the expansion of $(a + b)^p$ vanish modulo $p$, and you're left with the two ends: $a^p + b^p$.

Answer (score 7):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, if $c\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is prime, then $c^p\equiv c \mod p$.

So, since $(a+b)\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is prime,  $(a+b)^p\equiv (a+b) \mod p$

Also, since $a\equiv a^p \mod p$ and $b \equiv b^p \mod p$ (by Fermat's Little Theorem), we know that $a+b\equiv a^p+b^p \mod p$.

Thus $(a+b)^p \equiv a^p +b^p \mod p$.